# “Undefined definition” error in lex program

Tags: lex, flex-lexer

I am writing a lex program. The objective of this problem is that I enter a string Exemple Name@PhoneNumber also the first letter in the name should be uppercase letter

```
letterMin ([a-z])
letterMaj ([A-Z])
Letter ({letterMaj}({letterMin})*)
Number ([0-9])
Chaine ({letter}@({Number})*)
%%
{Chaine} printf("enter your chaine");
.* printf("Lexical Error");
%%
int yywrap(){return 1;}
main ()
{
yylex ();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to symbol names, case is important.  You want something like this:

```
letterMin ([a-z])
letterMaj ([A-Z])
letter ({letterMaj}({letterMin})*)
Number ([0-9])
Chaine ({letter}@({Number})*)
```

Comment: it's ok but i don't know what's the difference between my Code and your Code !

Comment: You defined your symbol `Letter` with a capital L, but tried to refer to it as `letter`, with a small L.

Comment: Thanks for your help i will need you maybe because i'm doing a project in Flex and Bison right now so if i have problem i will ask :)